# dynamic transformation and execution using kettle in java

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, spoon

how to create a ETL transformation in java and execute them like in spoon DI and what maven dependencies are needed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You may try reading this blog:
https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2015/01/18/java-and-pentaho-kettle-executing-a-kettle-file-using-java/

Hope it will help :)

Comment: thanks for your help. I appreciate it but somehow I was looking any illustration of creating kettle transformation/ job in java before running it. If you have any idea on this, please share.

Comment: Ktr or kjb files are nothing but XML files. Though i haven't tried coding these files from the start. I assume you can do it by placing the correct xml node in you java code. But this will be a really tedious job !!! Suggest you to use pentaho suite and create a ktr and if required run it using java.